# Error on deploying website to IIS - App still refers to local files directory even after publish

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-deployment, object-reference, publishing-site

Has anyone experienced this issue before? I published a website using File Deploy and placed it in an IIS. Other apps works just fine, but the website I deployed shows this error:

[image]

It seems to still be pointing to my local directory. I've updated the paths but to no avail. Help please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: File names/line numbers shown in exception call stack are information saved in symbol files (generated by the compiler on the development machine), so they are irrelevant to the actual issue. To fix null reference exception, revise your code to handle null.

Comment: Sometimes this issue could happen when the IIS application pool's identity doesn't have the required permission to access some resources, please try to change the application pool identity to some other accounts like LocalSystem or Network Service and try again [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).

Answer (score 0):

The paths show locations at compile-time, that is not a problem. Here, you are getting an exception on line 65 in DataAccess.cs - object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

If you set custom error "on" (in the web.config), you can get more info about the exception. In the "Network" tab of "Developer tools", you can check your request and response.